# is it possible to restrict access to one particular case case type?

Tags: civicase

I am unable to find an answer to this, so hoping someone will be able to point me in the direction of a solution....

We work with vulnerable older adults and as such may occasionally have to record safeguarding concerns according to legal requirements and our own policies and procedures and some actions must take place within certain delays.

I thought the best way to go about this would be to create a case template with a set of activities on a timeline (open case, concern reported, concern report to relevant safeguarding adult board, etc... etc... with 'case resolved' at the end.) So far it seems feasible.

I have a problem, this case would need to be seen only by

- the staff safeguarding lead (who would be the person managing the case)
- a senior manager with some safeguarding responsibility
  at least to ensure at least one person is always available for reporting.

How could I make these cases only visible / accessible by 'need to know' only individuals?

I saw that I can create cases and tick 'restrict to group' but it seems that this would only limit who the assignees can be, and the case would still be visible by others....

Thanks for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cms permissions create three roles:

- One that has "access all cases" permission
- One that has "access my cases"
- One that has neither

Then give the senior managers the first role and the case managers the second. Give everyone else the third.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#cms-permissions

Comment: I don't think I can make this work.  'Safeguarding Lead' is a role associated with a staff member who might not be the case manager so case manager should not be able to view the details of the safeguarding case notes  Everyone in the team can potentially work on everyone's cases as all are part-time, so I don't think that technically I could use the role with the 'neither' permission or they would no longer be able to see anything no?  Which is why I was wondering if there was a way of creating a specific template with a 'private' value, or something like that if that makes sense

Comment: I'm a little confused. It sounds like you're saying the person who has been assigned as the case manager shouldn't be able to see the case notes?

Comment: yes it can be confusing and I also used words wrong :-) what I meant was that the person who normally deals with the member and reports the concerns to the safeguarding lead will not be allowed to see the details of interactions and exchanges etc. recorded in the case notes. They are not the 'case manager' of the safeguarding case, sorry, that was confusing!   But the other bit remains, that if I set up a role for everyone else but the safeguarding lead without access to cases, then no one will be able to see any case - is that right?

Comment: Maybe try https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-type-acl, and then the safeguarding notes can be made using activity types you choose to be protected. I'm not sure how that extension works with cases but if it doesn't you could maybe still record those notes as regular activities.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like something that would work probably. I agree if we have to record the safeguarding notes as discrete activities it is not too much of a problem; more important that the notes are confidential. Thank again for taking the time to help

Comment: When you make an Activity Type you can set it to be for Cases ONLY, or Cases and Contacts. I would expect that if you set it to Cases ONLY, then it inherits the automatic ACL stuff that is built in to CiviCase - ie non-Case admins would not see them. If that is not true then maybe the docs need some nuancing.

Comment: No really the only thing that does is hides it from the type dropdown on regular activities. Maybe 1 or 2 other little things.